# Is downvoting question purely written in foreign language acceptable

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I concern to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672647/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-c-sharp-mvc) written in pure russian and which probably is going to be removed in a few seconds.

I think downvoting is not appropriate here as we simply do not know any of the OPs affords so we cannot say: OP did not try any own research. It could even be possible that the question - correctly translated - is a real good one.

However we MAY flag it as off-topic for another site of stackexcahange. So what is the appropriate way to do so?

Comment: Luckily (with all those downvotes), it *isn't* a good question, even translated.

Comment: Fortunately yes, but if it were a good one, what should we do?

Comment: Nothing. It's so unlikely it's a good question, it's not worth establishing a rule around this. See below.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly acceptable to downvote for it being in a foreign language. The tooltip for a downvote says "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." I'd say that being in a foreign language definitely makes it "unclear or not useful." Also, I'd argue that not reading the site rules constitutes a lack of research effort on their part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just let it run its natural course, which is towards deletion.

When questions in foreign languages are eventually deleted, the downvotes will be neutralized.

You're going to have a hard time arguing that questions in foreign languages should be exempt from downvoting - after all the mere fact of their posting on English SO means they didn't do enough research to realize that posts in their language isn't welcome here.

Flagging for migration is also a non-starter: the golden rule of migrating questions is [Don't Migrate Crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446). A question that was posted on the wrong language site is *very* likely to be crap.